# bubble chart with highstock

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

Can we do a bubble chart with highstock ??  if yes i need help please because i do it but it didn't work:

```
       $(function () {
         $('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{

            chart: {
                type: 'bubble',

            },

            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
            },

            series: [{
                data: [[Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27),97,36,79],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10),94,74,60],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18),68,76,58],
                ]
            }]

        });
        });
```

thank you

Answer (score 5):

You must use:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b826C/7/

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bubble'
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        navigator:{
            enabled:true
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled:true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Bubble Highstock',
            data: [[Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27),36,79],[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10),74,60],[Date.UTC(1970, 12, 20),76,58]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: The correct URL for `highcharts-more.js` is `http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js`. This will make sure it works correctly with the given Highstock version. All URLs are listed on http://code.highcharts.com/.