# Bubble chart with Highstock, how to create different tooltips?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, highcharts, series

I am in the [process of creating a Bubble Chart with Highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350075/bubble-chart-with-highstock). I want to know if it is possible to change the series name's data to something like this:

```
data: [{name:'any words 1',x:Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), y:2.07, z:1},{name:'any words 
2',x:Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), y:1.03, z:1}]}
```

I want to make individual tooltips with `this.point.name` to show some additional information.

Comment: Have you tried your own solution, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, then only what you need is extract this information in the tooltip by point.format or tooltip.formatter.

```
 tooltip:{
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/> {point.name}'
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b826C/45/